# How to implement least in mysql query without count 0?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to implement least in mysql query but least should not be count 0 how can i do that?

this is my query

```
    LEAST(price, price_double, price_triple, price_quad) AS minvalue
```

it is counting 0 right now but i dont want to count 0 and search the result with out having zero

For example

```
   price            100
   price_double     75
   price_tripple    50
   price_quad       0
```

the minvalue will be 50 not 0, but right now it is including 0.

Please help me to do that, i m in very trouble, i search a lot but didn't get any success, thanks a million ton thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` in the `least()` function to do this.  Unfortunately, `least()` returns NULL if any arguments are NULL in the more recent versions of MySQL.  So, this uses a dummy value that is big:

```
least(case when price > 0 then price else 999999 end,
      case when price_double > 0 then price_double else 999999 end,
      case when price_triple > 0 then price_triple else 999999  end,
      case when price_quad > 0 then price_quad else 999999 end
     )
```

Comment: thanks to all  answer work for me but the gordn answer work exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Use where clause

```
 SELECT LEAST(price, price_double, price_triple, price_quad)
 FROM ....
 WHERE LEAST(price, price_double, price_triple, price_quad) > 0
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me..I don't get 50, I get empty result: `SELECT LEAST(100, 75, 50, 0) FROM ... WHERE LEAST(100, 75, 50, 0) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

This is the same like Gordon Linoff's solution only a little shorter:

```
LEAST
(
    IF(price > 0, price, 999999),
    IF(price_double > 0, price_double, 999999),
    IF(price_triple > 0, price_triple, 999999),
    IF(price_quad > 0, price_quad, 999999)
)
```